# Delphi - UDP send looped message to my own IP (but not localhost)

Tags: delphi, udp, indy10

I'm sorry if this has been asked and/or resolved/covered somewhere else, but I couldn't find it, nor solve it myself by now.

*I've had a lot of success with working with UDPClient and UDPServer components, since I've done bunch of different apps with them and I got a lot of different solutions and help right here, on SO, and the answers served me perfectly well. However, I can't figure this one out.*

I have an app (not mine, publicly available), that can only use one network interface at a time.  Now I want to communicate with that app from within my application, using UDP components, but I need to leave the main app connected to the LAN Ethernet adapter, because I'm not the only one that wants to talk to the app (It is a console to control network based hardware devices, but accepts inputs as well).

Having that app assigned to use LAN interface on 2.0.0.2, so far the only success I've had is to use another USB interface on 2.0.0.3, bind my app to that interface, and send data to the 2.0.0.2 destination. 
Now, since obviously localhost / 127.0.0.1 won't work, I want to know what other options would be to send the data directly to the adapter with some kind of loopback, instead of using actual second interface and send the data through the hub?

I've tried to bind the same interface 2.0.0.2 on different port, and send the data to the same IP 2.0.0.2, but nothing is sent (Even Wireshark shows up empty traffic on LAN adapter).

Edit: Broadcasted message also doesn't work if I bind to the 2.0.0.2 adapter...

Looking for suggestions. Thanks.

Oh, using Delphi XE3 with Indy 10.

Comment: "*I've tried to bind the same interface 2.0.0.2 on different port, and send the data to the same IP 2.0.0.2, but nothing is sent (Even Wireshark shows up empty traffic on LAN adapter).*" Of course Wireshark won't show the traffic, it's loopback traffic that doesn't go on any wire. This should work, you need to try to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: When a UDP socket is bound to a specific IP/port and is reading inbound packets from it, sending packets from a local client socket directly to the bound IP/port works fine when I test it. You do not need to bind the sending client to any specific IP/port first, let the OS pick a suitable IP/port for you. Any packet sent to the bound IP, even sent locally, will be received by that IP as long as the destination port matches.

Comment: So, if I got it correctly, no matter to what I'm binding the UDPServer, if I send to the IP of the local adapter, it should work? Also, does it make any difference if I use UDPClient to send or UDPServer component? (No, I don't really need server in my case).  Also, does it differ if I use UDPServer.SendBuffer or UDPServer.Binding.SendTo  procedures?

Comment: Also, just for information : would it still work if I don't have anything connected to that ethernet port, ie no cable inserted? For like local testing...? Just to know if I need to make testings with cable plugged it or should it work without it as well...

Comment: @JustMarc If Ethernet card is not connected to any other network device then it does not any IP assigned to it. This means that you would not be able to do any testing on it at that time. BTW when testing some network applications I strongly recommend setting up a virtual environment using WMWare for instance. Why? When doing so you can recreate virtual network structure of multiple computers so the network traffic would act exactly as it would on real network. Such network would also simulate some network lag so you can see how lag can affect your application. ...

Comment: ... Lag is absent when working with LocalHost. Also you can get good ide of how different FireWall settings on specific client could effect your application. And the best thing about using WMWare for virtualization is that it can connect that virtual network with your real LAN network if your computer is connected to it. This also allows other computers on LAN to communicate with your virtual machines. The only thing that I miss with WMWare is to be able to cause bigger network lag out of the box. But for that there are multiple programs available on the net (net limiters)

Comment: @JustMarc: If you send a packet to an IP/port that `TIdUDPServer` or `TIdUDPClient` is bound to, it will receive the packet, even if sent locally. You can use `TIdUDPClient` or `TIdUDPServer` for sending, it will send using whichever IP/Port it is locally bound to, whether explicit or implicit (if you don't explicitly bind `TIdUDPClient`, it will bind on the first send). `SendBuffer()` calls `Binding.SendTo()` internally. If `TIdUDPServer` is bound to only 1 adapter, `SendBuffer()` will use that, but if bound to multiple adapters (multiple `Bindings`), it will use the first available binding.

Comment: @JustMarc: an adapter needs a physical cable to be plugged in to get an IP only if it is configured to receive its IP via DHCP. If a static IP is assigned to the adapter (you can do that in the adapter properties), you can bind and receive local packets on that adapter without needing a cable.